# jQuery memory game

Tags: jquery

I came across this jQuery memory game http://jsbin.com/ozidig/1/
but I'd like to have it with two different images for a pair.
Additionally for each match a different message would appear.

I think I should make an array with the two images and an id for the match,
after that I shall check for the match.
If there is a match the message with the id of the match would appear.

But I got stuck creating the array...
Does anyone know hot to add this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you exactly want.

In jQuery, you can store ids of images like this:

```
var imageIds = new Array();

$("img").each(function(index){
    imageIds[index] = $(this).attr("id"); 
})
```